# Break from SELECT CASE

Tags: select, fortran, case, break

Unlike C, Fortran does not need a break in each case. But is there a way to jump out of the select case statement besides `goto`? (I'd rather choose another way to jump if possible and I cannot use exit in select case statement.)

```
select case(key)
case("cat")
    if(value > 5) !break!
case("dog")
...
endselect
```

Here is an more detailed example. Though there are other types of flow control, break will be the best in my opinion

```
integer, allocatable :: Err(:)
select case(key)
case("cat")
    if(value1 > 5) call PushBack(Err, 1001)
    if(NotANumber(value2)) call PushBack(Err, 1002)
    if(value3 /= "good") call PushBack(Err, 1003)
    if(allocated(Err)) !break!
    .... !some processing
case("dog")
    ....
endselect
if(allocated(Err)) call ShowError(key, Err)
```

If I put everything in if:

```
integer, allocatable :: Err(:)
select case(key)
case("cat")
    if(value1 > 5) then            !Here only one of the value1, value2... is checked
        call PushBack(Err, 1001)
    elseif(NotANumber(value2)) then
        call PushBack(Err, 1002)
    elseif(value3 /= "good") then
        call PushBack(Err, 1003)
    else
        .... !some processing
case("dog")
    ....
endselect
if(allocated(Err)) call ShowError(key, Err)
```

If there are better solutions, please let me know.

Comment: If you cannot `exit` because you lack the compiler support (remember to name the `select case` construct) then this is a perfectly valid use of `goto` to my mind.  Much better than tedious workarounds.

Comment: I am using IVF on windows. I got this message: error #6602: A CYCLE or EXIT statement must not be used with a non-DO block

Comment: `exit`-ing a construct and `goto`-ing the end of a construct are syntactically and semantically equivalent.  Avoiding `goto` for the purpose, just because *goto considered harmful*, doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: This what `goto` is for. No need to avoid it in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have encountered an improvement introduced in Fortran 2008 that is not fully implemented in compilers. In Fortran 2008 `exit` can be used relating to things other than `do` loops.

I consider three approaches valid:

```
case1: select case(key)
case("cat")
  if (value > 5) exit case1
case("dog")
...
end select case1
```

This is the Fortran 2008 way.

```
case1: select case(key)
case("cat")
  if (value > 5) goto 1  ! Let's pretend this is an exit: we'll have compiler
                         ! support soon enough, and we can replace with exit
case("dog")
...
end select case1
1 continue
```

This is fake-Fortran 2008 way.  The comment is vital to this approach.

```
massive_hack: do k=1,1
  select case(key)
    case("cat")
      if (value > 5) exit massive_hack
    case("dog")
      ...
  end select case1
end do massive_hack
```

This is the Fortran 2003/hating `goto`s way.

All of these are preferable, to me, to introducing spurious flow-control within cases.

---

Explanation:

The wording in the Fortran 2003 standard for the `exit` statement is:

> The EXIT statement provides one way of terminating a loop.
>
> ...
>
> An EXIT statement belongs to a particular DO construct. If the EXIT statement refers to a DO construct name, it belongs to that DO construct; otherwise, it belongs to the innermost DO construct in which it appears.

whereas Fortran 2008 extends that with:

> The EXIT statement provides one way of terminating a loop, or completing execution of another construct.
>
> ...
>
> An EXIT statement belongs to a particular construct. If a construct name appears, the EXIT statement belongs to that construct; otherwise, it belongs to the innermost DO construct in which it appears.

The `select case` construct is one to which the above explicitly applies.

[Cursory glances](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2647342.2647345) suggest current versions of the Cray, NAG, GCC and IBM compilers support this enhanced behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I like the massive_hack that you posted.

Comment: If you do want to jump out of the case block, then I'd suggest having the `goto`.  Intent will be a lot clearer than with an artificial single-trip "loop"; when the construct `exit` becomes supported by IVF (as it surely will) you won't be changing the structure so much.

Comment: yes. I'll use goto here. I'll see if Mark can give some other options. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Extended comment rather than answer ...

I don't understand what the problem is that @Francescalus has solved for you.  Only one of the `case`s will be executed, the break to the end of the `select case` construct is the way that Fortran behaves.  In your fragment:

```
select case(key)
case("cat")
    if(value > 5) !break!
case("dog")
...
endselect
```

only the line `if(value > 5) !break!` is executed if `cat` is selected.  If your fragment ought to have been

```
select case(key)
case("cat")
    if(value > 5) then
        break
    else
        long and tedious processing
    end if
case("dog")
...
endselect
```

well that's just a long-winded way of writing

```
select case(key)
case("cat")
    if(value <= 5) then
        long and tedious processing
    end if
case("dog")
...
endselect
```

The `break` statement (or some syntactic equivalent) is needed in C and its ilk because the default behaviour is to fall through at the end of each `case`.

It seems to me @Francescalus's `massive_hack` is an absolutely appropriate use of `exit` in Fortran 2008, enabling an exit from an enclosing `do` construct to terminate a computationally-heavy loop over a sequence of elements.

I expect I've missed the point entirely ....

Comment: This answer is better than mine in several ways.  I was assuming that without `exit`/`goto` there would be convoluted flow control within the case's block to get to the end of it rather than jumping out of the whole construct.  This answer much more simply addresses the question as asked.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I completely understand that there is other ways of flow control than just break. May be I didn't give a good example. In my code there are many if to check value1, value2... each of them will give an error number. They can be different types as well. I think using break is the best way since I may have a lot of cases. See edited example. And if you have a better idea, please comment.

Comment: if the flow control gets convoluted that usually (not always) indicates the logic is convoluted.  I find it usually worth the effort for readability to work at avoiding the `break/exit/goto's`

Comment: @george I agree with your statement of the flow control. But I don't think break/exit should be avoided. Since you may want conditional exit in different cases. What break/exist does is to end current loop/construct. You can read the code in my question for example, it is going to be a disaster if you don't use exit (not available in IVF for now).

Comment: sorry i don't see `if(not condition)then;code;endif` as a "disaster" compared to `if(condition)break;code`. Perhaps I've missed something but that seems to be all your example needs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with high-performance-mark that the constructed need for such a break (or exit) inside switch-case is flawed here. Not only in this switch-case-construct, but for all, one can always skip to the end by simply not executing the rest of that particular case. This is best achieved with one if-condition and putting the "additional processing" code into that if-block.

Of course, doing that multiple times increases your indentation level. But as usual, if that happens, you probably better move some of your complexity into a subroutine or function.

Therefore, neither EXIT nor GOTO is a good answer, here.